# Creation of Acroynm with Java

Tags: java

I am currently attempting to make a program that takes any string input and splits by the spaces to create an acronym. Currently the program only prints out the first letter of the first word input. I believe that the problem is with my for loop. Could someone care to take a look?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordSplitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String phraseToChange;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("This program builds acronyms");
        System.out.println("Enter a phrase:");
        phraseToChange = input.next();
        String[] phraseChanger = phraseToChange.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i <= phraseChanger.length; i++) {
            String s = phraseChanger[i];
            System.out.println(s.charAt(0));

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Is the problem with my for loop? I looked up the syntax and i thought that this was the correct solution however if I enter "Hello World" it will only print out H

Comment: @KevinMaldjian - you need to put things like the details in your **comment** in your **actual question** as an **edit** or better yet when you write the question to begin with. I sugguest you read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have better reception in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You never actually build the acronym using the first letter from each word.  Try this code instead:

```
String [] phraseChanger = phraseToChange.split(" ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i < phraseChanger.length ; i++) {
    sb.append(phraseChanger[i].charAt(0));
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Hmmm this solution is still giving me the same results, also i found out that  i <= phraseChanger.length should be i < phraseChanger.length

Comment: @KevinMaldjian I just tested this code on IntelliJ and it runs fine.  You must be doing something wrong on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this phraseToChange = input.next(); you have to put phraseToChange = input.nextLine(); it will work